# cake php 3.0 Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\AppController' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I just write(copy from document of cakephp 3.0) a controller with the following code:

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
namespace App\Controller;

class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo'hi';            
    }
}
```

But when i access this controller by `http://localhost/crud_cake/articles/`
it will result:

> The requested URL /crud_cake/articles/ was not found on this server.

Or when i access this by `http://localhost/crud_cake/src/Controller/ArticlesController.php` this will result in:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\AppController' not found in C:\wamp\www\crud_cake\src\Controller\ArticlesController.php on line 4

Comment: Calling the ArticlesController.php directly will never work, as this circumvents Cake completely. What happens when you try to access http://localhost/crud_cake/? Many different causes spring to mind, your .htaccess mod_rewrite or you routes could be faulty. How did you start this Cake project?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing [mod rewrite](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting).

Comment: Ya ..there is problem in mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally it's resolve.
The problem is in mod rewrite i just open httpd.conf and uncomment the
"LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
and restart the apache.